# Harvesting a file system

Tags: geonetwork

In GeoNetwork I try to harvest a directory containing some geographic files. The harvesting seems to work fine but I can't see records on the catalog.
Is there any documentation I could follow? Or do I have to load data into a GeoServer first?

Comment: There's no requirement to have anything in GeoServer (or any other OWS server software implementation), to have metadata records show in GeoNetwork.   If metadata harvesting from your geographic files has worked without issue, then I think the next step is to publish the records ~ https://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/3.6.x/ko/user-guide/publishing/index.html

Comment: Privileges for harvested records are set to "All", so records should be published after harvesting. Probably there is an XSL transformation to apply ?

 

75954 record(s) harvested in 11863 seconds

20 hours ago

    added: 9
    badFormat: 29
    total: 75954
    unknownSchema: 66920
    unretrievable: 72